# How do I get an axios.get call to stop, so that a new call has new data?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am doing an axios.get call on an API, in React. When I run it the first time, I get the results that I expect. When I run it the next time and search for the same thing, I get more results than I had originally. Then if I search again, for the same thing, I get even more results that I had the second time. It keeps adding new results to the old ones without starting a brand new search. If I search for a different keyword, then I get results with both the new keyword results and the old ones that I did before.

There is probably an easy fix to this, but how do I get it to discard the old results and create new ones?  I have tried creating CancelTokens, but haven't been successful.
I am currently putting the results into a new array and I set that array equal to nothing when I first render the component, so I don't understand how this problem is happening in the first place.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

```
async componentDidMount() {
    //searches the api for the hashtag that the user entered
    newArray.length=0;
    newArray=[];
    await axios.get(`https://laffy.herokuapp.com/search/${this.props.toSearch}`).then(function(response) {
        returnedKeywordSearch = response.data;
      }) //if the api call returns an error, ignore it
      .catch(function(err) {
        return null;
      });

      //goes through the list of locations sent from the api above and finds the latitude/longitude for each
      var count = 0;
      while (count < returnedKeywordSearch.length) {
        locationToSearch = returnedKeywordSearch[count].location;
        if (locationToSearch !== undefined) {
          var locationList = await axios.get(`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${locationToSearch}.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibGF1bmRyeXNuYWlsIiwiYSI6ImNrODlhem95aDAzNGkzZmw5Z2lhcjIxY2UifQ.Aw4J8uxMSY2h4K9qVJp4lg`)
          .catch(function(err) {
            return null;
          });

          if (locationList !== null) {
            if (Array.isArray(locationList.data.features) && locationList.data.features.length)  
             {
              locationCoordinates.push(locationList.data.features[0].center);
              if (returnedKeywordSearch[count].location!== null && returnedKeywordSearch[count].location!==""
                  && locationList.data.features[0].center !== undefined)
                {newArray.push({
                            id: returnedKeywordSearch[count].id, 
                            createdAt: returnedKeywordSearch[count].createdAt,
                            text: returnedKeywordSearch[count].text,
                            name: returnedKeywordSearch[count].name,
                            location: returnedKeywordSearch[count].location,
                            coordinates: locationList.data.features[0].center
                });
                }
            } 
          }
        }

        count++;
      }
//tweetSpots is set to null in the initial component state set up
      this.setState({tweetSpots: newArray});
      this.setState({ done: true}); //sets done to true so that loading animation goes away and map displays
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out this problem is actually on the server side in Express where the data isn't being reset. So, I'll close this one and open a question about Express.